# Post to nested fields with Django Rest Framework serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have setup my serializer to return nested content successfully.

However, I have not been able to post data within the nested fields.

I don't get an error when posting the data- but it only posts to the non-nested fields.

I would like for it to take the "name" field OR primary key (of model "TAG") for posting item.

Models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Whats happening?", max_length=100, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Serializers.py:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    taglevel = filters.CharFilter(taglevel="taglevel")
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name', 'taglevel', 'id')

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'tag', 'info')

def validate(self, data):
    print(self.initial_data.__dict__)
    data['tag_name'] = []
    if 'tag' in self.initial_data.keys():
        for entry in self.initial_data['tag']:     
            data['tag_name'].append(entry['name'])
    return data

def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)
    tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
    movie = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for tag_data in tags_data:
        Movie.objects.create(name=name, **tag_data)
    return movie
```

Sample of posting data:

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/Data/',{ "title": "TEST_title", "tag": [ { "name": "test1", "name": "test2" } ], "info": [] })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json should be.

```
{ 
"title": "TEST_title", 
"tag": [ {"name": "test1" },
        {"name": "test2"}
       ],
"info": []
}
```

---

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    taglevel = filters.CharFilter(taglevel="taglevel")

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name', 'taglevel', 'id')


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'tag')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        movie = Movie.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            movie.tag.create(**tag_data)
        return movie
```

Comment: This has not worked. I get a 500 error (traceback here-http://dpaste.com/0BB0ZE8). So I  changed "tag = " to "read_only=False". This no longer gave the 500 error- but only posted the non-nested data.

Comment: Sorry i didn't test it at first. But i tested it now, though i had to omit (for my testing) the `taglevel` field on the `Tag` serializer. But i also realized that your json data you're posting for tags aren't correct either. 1. you have duplicate keys in the dictionary. But this is how you'll create tags for a created movie,

Comment: Same issue again. Only posting data to the non-nested fields. I'm posting like this- r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/Data/',{ "title": "TEST_title", "tag": [ {"name": "test1" }, {"name": "test2"} ], "info": [] })